# SQL loop over columns and excute REPLACE statement

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to replace a CRLF character in a table in SQL Server. The statement for one column works and goes like this:

```
select REPLACE(REPLACE(col_name,char(13),''), char(10), '') from table_name
```

Now I would like to repeat this for every column in my table. I have the following script which is not working:

```
Declare @sql varchar(max) = ''

select @sql = @sql + 'select [' + c.name + '] REPLACE(REPLACE(' + c.name + ', char(13),''), char(10), '') from [' + t.name + ']; ' 
from sys.columns c
inner join sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
where t.name = table_name

EXEC (@sql)
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work and I get the following error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 24
Incorrect syntax near 'REPLACE'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 24
Incorrect syntax near 'REPLACE'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 24
Incorrect syntax near 'REPLACE'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1
```

Comment: Just noticed, you use select, but if you want to get rid of that you need update. Add this to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things;  <strike>as noted by the other answer</strike>  there needs to be a comma after the initial `[c.name]`. Also, to get a single quote inside the string, you need two single quotes. Hence, to get two single quotes together, you need four single quotes.

```
select @sql = @sql + 'select [' + c.name + '], REPLACE(REPLACE(' + c.name + ', char(13),''''), char(10), '''') from [' + t.name + ']; ' 
    from sys.columns c
    inner join sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
    where t.name = 'table_name'

    exec (@sql)
```

NB: `print(@sql)` is a great help in debugging such problems!

Comment: You have inconsistent usage of square brackets. And to be honest you shouldn't use them in this type of situation. You should eliminate the brackets and instead use QUOTENAME. When you hard code brackets like this if there is a bracket in the name it will crash. And it important enough to use them once you should be consistent. Still this is a good answer and worth of a +1.

Answer (score 2):

Add quotes, remove first `c.name` or add comma, instead of adding `[]` use QUOTENAME:

```
Declare @sql varchar(max) = ''

select @sql = @sql + 'select ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ', REPLACE(REPLACE(' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + ', char(13),''''), char(10), '''') from ' + QUOTENAME(t.[name]) + '; ' 
from sys.columns c
inner join sys.tables t 
    on c.object_id = t.object_id
where t.[name] = 'table_name'

EXEC (@sql)
```

**EDIT**

If you need to update change `@sql` part:

```
select @sql = @sql + 'UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(t.[name]) + ' SET ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' = REPLACE(REPLACE(' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + ', char(13),''''), char(10), '''') ; '
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way, variable is not set with replaced value, quotes are not double-quoted...

```
Declare @sql varchar(max) = ''

select @sql = @sql + 'select [' + c.name + '] = REPLACE(REPLACE(' + c.name + ', char(13),''''), char(10), '''') from [' + t.name + ']; ' 
from sys.columns c
inner join sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
where t.name = 'commasep'

select @sql
```